# How to convert two adjacent cols in Bootstarp 5 into two rows for small screen sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap for the first time. I'm making my application responsive for normal laptop screen as well as for iPad Mini(768 X 1024) and iPad Air(820 X 1180). Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-start">
      <span class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let i of data" > <!-- dynamic no. of dropdowns -->
         <p-dropdown styleClass="dropdown" [options]="i" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <button pButton label="reset" class="reset-button p-button-outlined"></button>
      <button pButton label="apply" class="apply-button" (click)="showDialog()"></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the normal screen:
[image]

And this is when I changed device to iPad Air:

[image]

The problem is that dropdowns are one below the other and same issue is there with the button. Is it possible to show them in separate rows. I mean All dropdowns in one row and all buttons in the next row. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: `sm`, with default breakpoint values, applies from `≥576px` to `<768px` device width. Your iPad Air is above those, regardless of whether you hold it in landscape or portrait mode.

Comment: Please do not tag a question like this with `bootstrap-4` and `bootstrap-5` at the same time. Make it the version you are actually using.

Comment: its in Portrait mode only. Also Its not a real iPad device. I'm using Chrome's built in device screens.

Comment: So what, that doesn't change the fact that both 820 and 1180 are larger than 768.

Comment: Sure, I've removed `bootsrap-4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current situation, you're breaking the row into 2 columns at `md` or up. You'll probably need to break it at `lg` for your desired output for iPad.
You also need to add the `row` class to your inner div for its children to break into columns. Also you don't need to write `col-sm-12` to start with. The default is 12.

Something like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 text-start row">
      <span class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let i of data" > <!-- dynamic no. of dropdowns -->
         <p-dropdown styleClass="dropdown" [options]="i" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </span>
   </div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <button pButton label="reset" class="reset-button p-button-outlined"> 
    </button>
    <button pButton label="apply" class="apply-button" (click)="showDialog()"></button>
</div>
```

You'd probably need to apply more classes to the button divs to align them properly. I'd recommend adding a JSFiddle so we can debug better.

Answer (score 2):

its because you using `col-md-6` instead `col-md-12`. In bootstrap col are divided by 12, it means in medium device the size of col is `6/12` or `50%`. the children button and dropdowns forced to go down because the width is narrower than the element.

maybe you can try to add some another class to set width in medium device and large device like this.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-start">
      <span class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let i of data" > <!-- dynamic no. of dropdowns -->
         <p-dropdown styleClass="dropdown" [options]="i" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
      <button pButton label="reset" class="reset-button p-button-outlined"></button>
      <button pButton label="apply" class="apply-button" (click)="showDialog()"></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

but you still must set the buttons and dropdowns width. if you not set it, it will forced to go down.

you can check the default breakpoints here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints